# Ensure minimum string length

Tags: javascript

I want to ensure that I get a minimum length of 2 otherwise it should be filled with `" "`. For example:

```
let string = "  "
string.unknownMethod("a")
```

What function do I need in place of `unknown method` to get this output `" a"`. But if `string.unknownMethod("ab")` the output should be `"ab"`

Comment: What should it be for `string.unknownMethod("abc")`? What have you tried?

Comment: What do you mean "reserve" 2 characters? What is your expected output when `string` is `"  "`?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to ensure that you get a string with a minimum length of 2 characters and, otherwise, get it filled with leading spaces, it's easier if you reverse your current logic:

```js
console.log("".padStart(2, '-'));
console.log("a".padStart(2, '-'));
console.log("ab".padStart(2, '-'));
console.log("abc".padStart(2, '-'));
```

Spaces replaced with `-` for visibility.

Otherwise, you need to mess with substring offsets or regular expressions. It's doable but not as immediate.

[Reference for `padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)